# Sqlite and SqlServer providers exception types

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I use for two providers for Entity Framework Core in my ASP.NET Core application. `SqlServer` for production mode and `Sqlite` for integration tests mode.

In my application `DbContext`, when an exception occurs during `SaveChangesAsync`, I catch it to know what kind of problem occurred. I do that to be able to detect unique index constraint violation for example.

I have the following problems: it seems that different exception types are created for `Sqlite` and `SqlServer` providers (`SqlException` and `SqliteException`). These exceptions have different `ErrorCode` so I have to always specify the two error codes if I want to detect one kind of error.

Did someone find any solution to easily manage usual relational database errors and to get the same exception handler work for many providers ?

More of that, do you have any solution to know what is the type of the entity throwing the exception or do we have to get it from the string `Message` included in the exception?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server error codes, you can refer here: [Database engine errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors)

For Sqlite error codes, you can refer here: [Result and Error Codes](https://sqlite.org/rescode.html)

For getting the entity, you will not know that from `SqlException`. But you can catch more specific exceptions. For instance, `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` has an `Entries` property you can work with.

Reference: [Resolving concurrency conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency)

Here is an example for an handling an auth error that might work for you:

```cs
try
{
    ⋮
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    foreach (SqlError sqlError in e.Errors)
    {
        switch (sqlError.Number)
        {
            case 10028:
            {
                HandleAuthError(e);
                break;
            }
            ⋮
        }
    }
}
catch (SqliteException e)
{
    switch (e.SqliteErrorCode)
    {
        case 23:
        {
            HandleAuthError(e);
            break;
        }
        ⋮
    }
}

private void HandleAuthError(SystemException e)
{
    ⋮
}
```

Note : In 3.0.1, a bug makes that Entries Collection is empty when a unique index constraint violation is raised... Supposed to be fixed in 3.1

Comment: Pattern matching only adds overhead here. You can catch the exceptions directly.

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot !

But you agree that I can't use the same code to handle same errors for the two providers.. The thing that is problematic for me is that tests could pass with Sqlite provider but my application could not work with Sqlserver if I forgot some cases for SQLServer provider.

In your example, If I make a mistake and I write sqlError.Number 10027, the tests will pass without any problem. But in production, it won't be the same behavior...